# opening link in external browser from page in WebView

Tags: javascript, angular, android-webview

I'm developing an angular website which is loading in an app from a WebView, and there is only one of the links in it that has to be opened outside of the app (external browser)

I need a way to handle this from JavaScript not putting extra work to the android side.
and i have already tried some ways including:

`window.open("url","_system")`

`(navigator as any).app.loadUrl("http://google.com", {openExternal : true});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is no such thing

instead it must be handled from android application code. you can add a parameter to the url when u need it to open in external browser, ( here it is `external=true` ) and then check for that parameter in your webview url loading as below:

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                if((String.valueOf(request.getUrl())).contains("external=true")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, request.getUrl());
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    view.loadUrl(String.valueOf(request.getUrl()));
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where to add this url?'

Comment: @Arj1411 what do you mean? please describe your situation. the URL is a link in the website